# What is the mechanism behind Function Application in Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming

OK, let me try to rephrase my question.

Actually I wanted to know how is Function Application implemented in FP.

Is it done like a function call in imperative languages, where a stack frame is added for each call and removed on each return.

Or, is it like in inline functions, where the function call statement is replaced by the function definition.

Also, in terms of implementation of a function application, what is the significance of the statement *functions in FP are mappings between domains and corresponding ranges*. It is obviously not possible to maintain a *mapping* for each domain-range entry pair, so what exactly does the statement imply...

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind the down vote, coz. I really want to know how functions in FP are put to work. I come to FP with an imperative background and wish to understand what happens behind the scenes...

Comment: Not a DV but can imagine at least two possible reason: it's not entirely clear what you're asking here because you're promiscuously mixing abstraction levels (e.g. language use and underlying implementation) and to the extent that it is comprehensible it reads as pointless semantic hair splitting. There's absolutely nothing about functional languages that in any way suggests that their underlying implementations are pure. Nor is it clear what you are talking about with references to manipulating a call stack? Inline functions in C++? I just don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

This question is broad enough that I can't answer it completely, since I don't know every single functional programming language. But I can tell you how it's done in *one* language, F#. You asked whether function application is done like a function call in imperative languages (another stack frame added for each call) or whether it's done as inline functions... and in F# the answer is *both*. The F# compiler is allowed to choose whether to create a stack-frame-using function call, or whether to inline the function at the call site; generally the choice is made based on the size of the compiled function. If the function compiles down to fewer than N bytes of compiled code (I can't tell you the exact number, but knowing the exact number doesn't actually matter) then the compiler will usually inline that function call; if it takes more than N bytes then the function call will use a stack frame. (Except in the case of tail-recursive calls, which are compiled to the equivalent of a `goto` and don't use a stack frame).

P.S. You can force the compiler's hand by using the `inline` keyword, which forces that function to be inlined at the call site every time. Most F# programmers don't recommend doing that on a regular basis, because the compiler is smart enough that it's usually not a good idea to override its decisions. (Also, the `inline` keyword means that the types of the function's parameters must be resolvable at compile time, so there are some functions for which that changes the semantics, but that's a little off-topic for the question you asked so I won't go into it. Except to say that in F#, statically-resolved type parameters or SRTPs are a very complicated subject, and you can do some very advanced things with them if you understand them.)